# JAVA SSL Generate a new keystore certificate for each client on server side

Tags: java, ssl, keystore

I am trying to make my help-desk chat application secure. On my client side, I created it so that each client would create their certificate and keystore at runtime (so not every client has the same keystore), and exactly same on server. However, on the server side, this takes place before the while loop that accepts connections from clients. This means that the server is using the same certificate for each connection, which would make it very easy for a malicious user to send data to the server simply by using the server's certificate (which is the same the whole time the server is up).

Can I somehow create the certificate and keystore IN the while loop in the server, and somehow use that certificate for the new incoming connection (sslsocket.accept). (BTW, I can only use one server port for all connections).

The following is my client implementation (snippet):

```
String domainName ="localhost";

KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator;
Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider ());

keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");

keyPairGenerator.initialize(1024);
KeyPair KPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();

X509V3CertificateGenerator v3CertGen = new X509V3CertificateGenerator(); 

v3CertGen.setSerialNumber(BigInteger.valueOf(Math.abs(new SecureRandom().nextInt())));
v3CertGen.setIssuerDN(new X509Principal("CN=" + domainName + ", OU=None, O=None L=None, C=None"));
v3CertGen.setNotBefore(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30));
v3CertGen.setNotAfter(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365*10)));
v3CertGen.setSubjectDN(new X509Principal("CN=" + domainName + ", OU=None, O=None L=None, C=None"));

v3CertGen.setPublicKey(KPair.getPublic());
v3CertGen.setSignatureAlgorithm("MD5WithRSAEncryption");

X509Certificate pkCertificate = v3CertGen.generateX509Certificate(KPair.getPrivate());  

KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
keystore.load(null, null);
Random rand = new Random();
String x = rand.nextInt(1000000000) + "";
char[] passCert = x.toCharArray();
keystore.setKeyEntry("user", KPair.getPrivate(), passCert, new X509Certificate[] {pkCertificate});
FileOutputStream fos;

fos = new FileOutputStream("cert.cert");
fos.write(pkCertificate.getEncoded());
fos.close();
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
Random rand2 = new Random();
String y = rand2.nextInt(1000000000) + "";
char[] password = y.toCharArray();
ks.load(null, password);
PrivateKeyEntry entry = new PrivateKeyEntry(KPair.getPrivate(),
    new java.security.cert.Certificate[]{pkCertificate});
ks.setEntry("newuser",entry , new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(password));

fos = new FileOutputStream("mySrvKeystore2");
ks.store(fos, password);
fos.close();
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "mySrvKeystore2");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", y);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "mySrvKeystore");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "harinder99");
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
    new X509TrustManager() {
        public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }

        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }
    }
};
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
kmf.init(ks, y.toCharArray());
SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
ctx.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket(server, hh);
```

The following is my server implementation (snippet).

```
String domainName ="localhost";

KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator;
Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider ());

keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");

keyPairGenerator.initialize(1024);
KeyPair KPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();

X509V3CertificateGenerator v3CertGen = new X509V3CertificateGenerator(); 


v3CertGen.setSerialNumber(BigInteger.valueOf(Math.abs(new SecureRandom().nextInt())));
v3CertGen.setIssuerDN(new X509Principal("CN=" + domainName + ", OU=None, O=None L=None, C=None"));
v3CertGen.setNotBefore(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30));
v3CertGen.setNotAfter(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365*10)));
v3CertGen.setSubjectDN(new X509Principal("CN=" + domainName + ", OU=None, O=None L=None, C=None"));

v3CertGen.setPublicKey(KPair.getPublic());
v3CertGen.setSignatureAlgorithm("MD5WithRSAEncryption");

X509Certificate pkCertificate = v3CertGen.generateX509Certificate(KPair.getPrivate());  

KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
keystore.load(null, null);
Random rand = new Random();
String x = rand.nextInt(1000000000) + "";
char[] passCert = x.toCharArray();
keystore.setKeyEntry("user", KPair.getPrivate(), passCert, new X509Certificate[] {pkCertificate});
FileOutputStream fos;

fos = new FileOutputStream("cert.cert");
fos.write(pkCertificate.getEncoded());
fos.close();
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
Random rand2 = new Random();
String y = rand2.nextInt(1000000000) + "";
char[] password = y.toCharArray();
ks.load(null, password);
PrivateKeyEntry entry = new PrivateKeyEntry(KPair.getPrivate(),
      new java.security.cert.Certificate[]{pkCertificate});
ks.setEntry("newuser",entry , new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(password));

fos = new FileOutputStream("mySrvKeystore3");
ks.store(fos, password);
fos.close();
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "mySrvKeystore3");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", y);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "mySrvKeystore");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "harinder99");
/////
clientSocket = null;
ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
SSLServerSocket server1 = (SSLServerSocket)null;
String port = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Port: ", "1234");
try {
    //SSLServerSocketFactory sslserversocketfactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
        new X509TrustManager() {
           public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
           }

           public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
           }

           public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
               return null;
           }
       }
   };
   KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
   kmf.init(ks, y.toCharArray());
   SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
   ctx.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
   SSLServerSocketFactory sslserversocketfactory = ctx.getServerSocketFactory();
   server1 = (SSLServerSocket) sslserversocketfactory.createServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(port));
```

Comment: Using self-singed client certificates doesn't add any security to the system as this only ensures that client is capable of producing them, which is not big deal. On the other hand, TLS uses key pairs, rather than single certificate, so using the same keypair for all connections on server side is fine. And last thing - your trust manager accepts all certificates, even invalid ones, which spoils the whole idea of using TLS.

Answer (score 0):

> This means that the server is using the same certificate for each connection, which would make it very easy for a malicious user to send data to the server simply by using the server's certificate (which is the same the whole time the server is up).

No it wouldn't. The server certificate is no use to anyone for forgery purposes without the server's private key, which you need to keep private of course. It isn't advertised by anything to do with SSL.

Your problem is imaginary.